# Variable width navbar

Tags: css

Is there any way to make a variable width navbar, I don't know how to make variable the clickable area... http://jsfiddle.net/tirengarfio/a9ssC/

As you can see, now I have set a 50px `padding` to the `anchor` tag, but I would like it to be variable actually..

This is the jsfiddle code:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:20px;
  background-color:red;
  border:2px solid;
}
li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align:center;
}
a {
 padding: 0 50px;   
}
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle is broken `Error 404
We're truly sorry, but there is no such page.` please fix that :)

Comment: @KeesSonnema, try this link: http://jsfiddle.net/C7wmM/

Comment: So what do you exactly mean by `I want it to be variable` ?

Comment: @KeesSonnema sorry, I edited the question

Comment: Did you try width: auto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>1jkflasd</li>
        <li>2jkflasd</li>
        <li>3jkflasd</li>
        <li>4jkflasd</li>
        <li>5jkflasd jffjadj faljdf aljf adjf ladjf lkdjf alsjdf ldsjf ldsjf </li>
        <li>6jkflasd</li>
        <li>7jkflasd</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: table-row;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:20px;
    background-color:red;
    border:2px solid;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The trick here is using the `table` as values of `display` in CSS.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/jlratwil/4srb6/1/

Comment: thanks, but..is there any way to do it without using `table` as values of `display`?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it with table, hacking css by javascript. Or you can use CSS3 also.
If you work with CSS3 your code should like this:

```
<style> 
    ul{
        display:-moz-box; /* Firefox */
        display:-webkit-box; /* Safari and Chrome */
        display:-ms-flexbox; /* Internet Explorer 10 */
        display:box;
        width:300px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }

    li {
        -moz-box-flex:1.0; /* Firefox */
        -webkit-box-flex:1.0; /* Safari and Chrome */
        -ms-flex:1.0; /* Internet Explorer 10 */
        box-flex:1.0;
        border:1px solid red;
    }
</style>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">jkflasd</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">jkflasd</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">jkflasd</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can read more about flexbox at here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp#flexbox